# how to capture pressure and area over touchscreen in android

Tags: android, touchscreen, touch-event, motionevent

I am using an Acer A500 (capacitive screen) 10" tablet with Android 3.2.1.  I am trying to capture the area of the finger touching the screen and also the amount of pressure over the screen.  I have tried Motionevent.getsize() and I always get a value of 0. Also, Motionevent.getpressure()  always gives me a value of 1.

Other functions like getX(), getY(), and getEventTime() seem to work fine.

Am I missing something? Is there anything else that I need to do?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Here is the code:

```
package com.mygroup.myapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent; 
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;

public class MultiTouchTest extends Activity implements OnTouchListener{
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
TextView textView;
float[] x = new float[10];
float[] y = new float[10];
double[] p = new double[10];
float[] s = new float[10];
long[] t = new long[10];
boolean[] touched = new boolean[10];


private void updateTextView(){
    builder.setLength(0);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        builder.append(touched[i]);
        builder.append(", ");
        builder.append(x[i]);
        builder.append(", ");
        builder.append(y[i]);
        builder.append(", pressure = ");
        builder.append(p[i]);
        builder.append(", size = ");
        builder.append(s[i]);
        builder.append(", time = ");
        builder.append(t[i]);
        builder.append("\n");
    }
    textView.setText(builder.toString());
}

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    textView = new TextView(this);
    textView.setText("touch:");
    textView.setOnTouchListener(this);
    setContentView(textView);
}
//@Override

public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event){
    int action = event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK;

    int pointerIndex = (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_MASK) >>
    MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_SHIFT;
    int pointerId = event.getPointerId(pointerIndex);

    switch(action){
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
        touched[pointerId] = true;
        x[pointerId] = (int)event.getX(pointerIndex);
        y[pointerId] = (int)event.getY(pointerIndex);
        p[pointerId] = event.getPressure(pointerIndex);
        s[pointerId] = event.getSize(pointerIndex);
        t[pointerId] = event.getEventTime();
        break;
               ...
    }
    updateTextView();
    return true;
}
```

}

Comment: A capacitive screen cannot, per design, give you the pressure applied on a point. It can only give you a position and a weight (i.e. the surface's ratio applied). It can't give you a precise surface in mm2, but you can correlate it. Only a resistive touch screen can give you the pressure applied, and have a really good dpi precision on touch events. HTH

Comment: Richard Martin, I have the same problem. Some of my capacitive devices get me different (true) size, but other always get 0.003921569. Did you win in this problem?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that those input report types are not enabled. You could try running this command under adb shell, it will print the possible event types that the touch controller supports:

```
getevent -pl
```